# Python - Finding word occurences amongst unique values of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have made a function to load a spreadsheet into a dataframe, and count the rows for the 'Product' column that has a word from a wordlist.

```
def wordlist_freq_count(filename, wordlist):
    xlsfile = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    dframe = xlsfile.parse('Sheet1')
    total_count = 0
    for word in wordlist:
        count = dframe.Product.str.contains(word, case=False).sum()
        total_count += count
    return total_count
```

What can I do to make it so that the dataframe only has unique Product values, or gives me a count of only the unique rows with the word occurences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `isin`

```
dframe.Product.isin(wordlist).sum()
```

If it so happens that the entries in the `Product` column may be more than the individual words in `wordlist` and you indeed want `contains`, then you can use a regex expression.

```
dframe.Product.str.contains('|'.join(wordlist)).sum()
```

Comment: Yeah the words in the wordlist (eg. 'improved') are supposed to be a subset of the Products values (eg. 'New and Improved Product'). What I wanted to know is - How do I get unique product listings in the dataframe, or just a count of the unique products that contain the words?

Comment: Please sample data in your post.